# how to access the devise @user instance variable outside of the devise controller & templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app that has user profiles, now bare in mind the user_profile.html.erb template is associated with the home_controller, not any devise controllers.

Now the problem is I want to put a form_for(@user) on the user_profile page and let users upload various photos with carrier wave, however I'm getting an undefined users_path error.

I've been messing around with this for hours and can't seem to figure it out.. I know it's probably a simple solution but at this point I have no idea, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Post your `config/routes.rb`. It's likely you don't have a path for `users`. Maybe add `resources :users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `current_user`:

```
form_for(current_user)
```

This of course assumes you've defined the `user_path` route within `config/routes.rb`.